# How to insert image file as individual for ontology class

Tags: ontology

im using protege 4.1 , and i have a class of animal and other class for images , i need to insert image file such as .jpg , .gif, .png as an individual for "Images" class to assign it to one instance of "Animal" class , how can i insert this image file ?

Comment: Do you think adding an image URL makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what do you mean with "insert" the class. If you have already classes *Animal* and *Image*, I'd create a relationship *hasImage*:

```
:Animal :hasImage :Image
```

For the *Image*, you can add relationships such as:

```
:Image :hasURL :URL
:Image :hasName :string
:Image :hasType :string
...
```

Note: this notation is not formal at all...

Comment: What I meant was how to save an image file within the owl file , like insert picture in microsoft word , so if the individual has data property (has_photo)  the value of this property will be a physical flie photo.jpg